# SQL - Why do the results from these 3 queries not add up?

Tags: mysql, sql

Each of the 3 queries below spits out a series of months along with the number of quotes created for each month. Each quote in the database has a username associated with it which is the email address of the person.

I would assume that the total for any single month from QUERY 1, should be the number for that month in QUERY 2 PLUS the number for that month in QUERY 3. But they don't add up.

For example, I would have thought that I get something like:

```
QUERY NUMBER 1
Aug 2013 -> 2836

QUERY NUMBER 2
Aug 2013 -> 2500

QUERY NUMBER 3
Aug 2013 -> 325
```

so 2500 (QUERY NUMBER 2) + 325 (QUERY NUMBER 3) = 2825 rather than 2836 (QUERY NUMBER 1)
and I'm not sure why it doesn't give me 2836

Looking at the queries below, why doesn't QUERY 2 + QUERY 3 = QUERY 1?
There's only one line that changes:

```
WHERE created_by_username = 'sysadmin@mydomain.co.uk'

//QUERY NUMBER 1  
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b %Y'),
       COUNT(DISTINCT username)
FROM view_all_quotes
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b %Y')
ORDER BY created ASC

//QUERY NUMBER 2  
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b %Y'),
       COUNT(DISTINCT username)
FROM view_all_quotes
WHERE created_by_username = 'sysadmin@mydomain.co.uk'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b %Y')
ORDER BY created ASC

//QUERY NUMBER 3  
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b %Y'),
       COUNT(DISTINCT username)
FROM view_all_quotes
WHERE created_by_username <> 'sysadmin@mydomain.co.uk'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b %Y')
ORDER BY created ASC
```

Sorry I can't find the documentation to advise on formatting SQL in these posts.

Comment: Prefix SQL with four spaces, or select the SQL lines and press Ctrl-K, or select the SQL lines and choose Code from the editor toolbox

Comment: My guess is that there are "missing" records in the last two queries because `created_by_username` is `Null`.

Comment: I'm struggling to pinpoint the issue. Could there be an issue with `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b %Y')` because when I remove that line, the cumulative number I get back is different to each of the last 6 months added together (I've restricted the queries to just show the last 6 months in my testing).

Comment: I've focused in one specific day and there is something more complex going on with the original data. I'm looking into it and will update asap.

Comment: I've found out what was going on and displayed the answer below on the original post. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

Rows where the `created_by_username` is `null` will be excluded by both `where` clauses.

You can find these rows with:

```
select * from view_all_quotes where created_by_username is null
```

Comment: I have updated the queries and run them again to only show me results from the last 6 months (they still don't add up). I then ran the following for those 6 months, which returned 0 results. Could anything else be happening? `select * from view_all_quotes where created_by_username is null
AND '2014-03-01' <= DATE_FORMAT( created,  '%Y-%m-%d' ) 
AND  '2014-09-01' > DATE_FORMAT( created,  '%Y-%m-%d' )`

Comment: Maybe it's related to `GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(created,'%b %Y')` please see comment above...

Comment: update - I've found out what was going on and displayed the answer below on the original post. Thanks for your help @Andomar

Answer (score 0):

When I wrote the question I thought that the error was in the queries I'd created. However since writing it I have found that there was nothing wrong with the queries, and there weren't any records missing.

But there were a small number of usernames that were appearing in BOTH QUERY 2 and QUERY 3 (correctly) and so QUERY 1 was combining those usernames meaning that the values/results returned by QUERY 1 were smaller than QUERY 2 + QUERY 3. Hope that makes sense. Sorry for wasting anyone's time. I didn't realise when writing the question that the answer would be in the data that only I could see.

Thanks again.